# How to create www.customer.appsglobal.com/login.aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-routing

I want to create a webisite like **`www.customer1.appsglobal.com/login.aspx`** using asp.net.
Here "**customer1**" is changed based on different customers. But remaining the url should be same.
        For this i have choosen IIS URL-Rewrite concept.

We have a domain is www.appsglobal.com. But using this we can create url's like

```
http://www.customer1.appsglobal.com/login.aspx
http://www.customer2.appsglobal.com/login.aspx
http://www.customer3.appsglobal.com/login.aspx
```

so please help me to do like this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: here is same discussion may be it can help. http://forums.asp.net/t/1795413.aspx

Comment: here is a free url-rewriter tool for asp.net http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/configuration

Answer (score 0):

What you have done there is make your customer name subdomain's, so your URL rewrite is not going to work. You will need to write a script that can create these sub domains for you, but I would suggest looking into your host if you don't manage your server your self.